# issue containerizing a localized angular app

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have a localized angular app that I am trying to containerize using docker.
The containerization process executes without any hiccups but I am not getting the expected outcome

Here's my dockerfile:

```
# Stage 1
FROM node:18.16.0 as node
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-dev
# Stage 2
FROM nginx:alpine
COPY --from=node /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

Here's my docker compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  meerkat:
    image: meerkat
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      ports: 
            - 8080:80
```

When I run the container, I see this:

[image]

I suspect that I a config issue is involved but not sure.

Thanks for any insight.